# Can I find out the return value before returning while debugging in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, return-value

Is it possible to see the return value of a method after the line has been run and before the instruction pointer returns to the calling function?

I am debugging code I can't modify *(read: don't want to re-compile a third party library)*, and sometimes it jumps to code I don't have source to or the return expression has side effects that stop me being able to just run the expression in the *Display* tab.

Often the return value is used in a compound statement, and so the *Variables* view will never show me the value (hence wanting to see the result before control returns to the calling function).

**UPDATE:** I can't use the expression viewer as there are side-effects in the statement.

Comment: That's why I switched to the Community Version of IntelliJ -- the Eclipse folks just don't seem to understand how important this is.  (If they ever fix it, I'll switch back the day it's released.)

Comment: @James Mitchell this looks like a great idea for a plugin. I will add it to me todo list and will try to do it when I find time(not soon)

Comment: @user672348 But how to do that in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @AlexeyTigarev: IIRC, it's just displayed when you do "Step Return" (or the equivalent).

Comment: Brace yourself for Eclipse Oxygen (mid 2017 release date). [The M2 milestone includes this feature](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/M2/#step-show-methodresult).

Comment: @user672348 and did you switch? :>

Comment: @Abdull: Thanks for pointing this out. I added it to the top answer.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This feature was added to Eclipse version 4.7 M2 under [Eclipse bug 40912](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=40912).

To use it:

- step over the `return` statement (using "Step Over" or "Step Return")
- now the first line in the variable view will show the result of the return statement, as "[statement xxx] returned: "

See [Eclipse Project Oxygen (4.7) M2 - New and Noteworthy](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/M2/#step-show-methodresult) for details.

Comment: Me, too.  I miss this feature when using Eclipse.

Comment: This Eclipse bug was subsequently [reopened in late 2009](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=40912#c16).  Still awaiting a fix, though, with no one assigned, and no Target Milestone. :)

Comment: This has been fixed in the recent builds of Eclipse 4.7 (M2 onwards)

Comment: Some information for how to use the fix can be found in the New And Noteworthy for 4.7 M2.  Look for "Method result after step operations" here: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/M2/

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg: Thanks for pointing this out - I edited it into the answer.

Answer (score 35):

Found a really good shortcut for this.
Select the expression which returns the value and press

```
Ctrl + Shift + D
```

This will display the value of the return statement. This is really helpful in cases where you can't or don't want to change just for debugging purpose.

Hope this helps.

Note: Have not tested this with third party libraries, but it is working fine for my code.
Tested this on *Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Juno Service Release 1*

Comment: +1 because this works not only for return values, but for expressions in general. Much more convenient than using the expressions tab. It should be noted this executes the code, so if it has side effects, beware. http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fmenus%2Frun%2Fref-menu-run.htm

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + I` was also helpful for me.

Comment: as @goat mentioned, this executes the code multiple times, so for example if the function did this `return System.currentTimeMillis();`, then you'd get a different result than the function actually returned!

Comment: Equivalent on an `Apple machine` ?

Comment: This is problematic advice - this will re-evaluate the expression, which can be disastrous if it has side-effects.

Answer (score 6):

That's why I always stick with the following pattern for methods:

```
MyReturnedType foo() {
     MyReturnedType   result = null;

     // do your stuff, modify the result or not

     return result;
}
```

My rules:

1. Only one return statement, only at the end of the method (finally allowed after it)
2. Always have a local called result which holds the returned value, starting from a default.

Naturally, the most trivial getters are exempt.

Comment: Hey zvikico - when I'm working on my own code, I usually use a similar pattern.
Unfortunately, my problem is when I'm using code that is not written or modifiable by me. :S

Comment: I do this too, but SonarLint is complaining....now I am equivocating:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31733811/local-variables-before-return-statements-does-it-matter/31734226#31734226

Comment: @WitoldKaczurba that's your opinion, and that's fine. Just accept that there are other opinions, and show some respect to those who do.

Comment: Hi zvikco. Thanks for message. I accept that there are different approaches but I referred to https://pmd.sourceforge.io/pmd-4.3.0/rules/design.html#UnnecessaryLocalBeforeReturn . Cheers

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a long standing bug in Eclipse, dating back from the very first days of the IDE: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=40912

Answer (score 2):

I am curious about to learn the answer to this question also.

In the past, when dealing with 3rd party library like that, what I did is to create a wrapper class or child class that delegate to the parent class and do my debugging in the wrapper/child class. It takes extra work though.

Comment: The problem with this solution (apart from the one you noted about extra work) is that it only works if you aren't multiple classes/methods deep inside an external library.

But it is useful when you are dealing with the outer layer of methods.

Answer (score 1):

"Now when you return from a method, in the upper method, in the variable view it shows the return value of the previously finished call" [1]

[1] https://coffeeorientedprogramming.wordpress.com/2016/09/23/eclipse-see-return-value-during-debugging/

Answer (score 0):

Tough one.  My experience, outside of Eclipse, is that if you might need to see the return value, it is best to assign it to a local variable in the function so that the return statement is a simple `return varname;` and not `return(some * expression || other);`.  However, that's not dreadfully helpful to you since you say you can't (or don't want to) modify or even recompile the code.  So, I don't have a good answer for you - perhaps you need to reconsider your requirement.

Comment: In my code I generally have the intermediate step so I can check the result, but some of the code I am using has too much organisational overhead to modify (esp. if the library gets updated, don't really want to maintain a forked version just for debugging).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the return statement, you can highlight the expression that is being returned and from the right-click menu, there should be something like "evaluate expression" (I don't have eclipse in front of me now, but it's something like that).  It will show you what is going to be returned.

Comment: The problem is when evaluating the return feature has side-effects (like database entries being created for instance), evaluating the return expression will change the system state. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit far-fetched, but as there doesn't seem to be a simple way:

You could use AspectJ to instrument the JAR with aspects that get hold of the return value of the methods you're interested in. According to Eclipse's documentation, AspectJ programs can be [debugged](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.ajdt.doc.user/questions/usingajdt/debugging.htm) like other programs.

There are two options to weave your classes without recompiling the library :

- Post-compile weaving if processing the binary JAR is acceptable;
- Load-time weaving, which requires activating a weaving agent in the VM.

See the eclipse documentation (link above) and also the [AspectJ Development Environment Guide](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

For @Daniel Meyer answer's to work, ensure that ***'Show method result after a step operation (if supported by the VM; may be slow)'*** is *checked*. The option is accessible via;

`Windows> Preferences> Java> Debug> Show method result......`