# How to get value returned by method in eclipse's debug?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, return, return-value

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I find out the return value before returning while debugging in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217116/can-i-find-out-the-return-value-before-returning-while-debugging-in-eclipse)

I have method like this

```
return doSomething(param1, param2);
```

doSomething does something in database, so I would rather not execute it again. How to get the returned value in debug?

P.S. I do know I can extract value to the variable, but sometimes that won't work (hotswap does not always work), plus it would be cool to not change that code if I do not need to (its not mine). plus I do know that checkstyle has a rule against assigning to variable before return, so there is no point to making the code less "quality".

Comment: you could select the code "doSomething(param1, param2)" and press "ctrl + shif + i" for inspect