# return value of main() in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

How can I inspect the return value of the main function in Eclipse?  I've search SO, google'd it and also searched through the [CDT FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ) but I can't find anything on this.  I'm using CDT at the moment.

Comment: Maybe this will be solved together with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217116/can-i-find-out-the-return-value-before-returning-while-debugging-in-eclipse some day.

Comment: Any luck with a solution? I'd like this too (especially since code blocks offers it, I think)